# Перекомпилировать приложение для переноса на другой сервер

Tags: android, ios

С разработкой с android и ios не сталкивался, есть два архива для android и для ios, стоит задача изменить ip сервера, так как производится  перенос с одного сервера на другой, сказали нужно перекомпилировать приложение. Подскажите где можно почитать посмотреть по данному вопросу

Comment: а что именно переносится?
если кратко, качаете android sdk и xcode, меняете ip - компилируете.

Comment: И не забудьте удостовериться что у вас есть правильные ключи для подписи приложений.

Comment: @Insider  серверная часть с базой данных и сайтом + парсер переносится с сервера на сервер,  я так понимаю ip задается при компиляции через программы android sdk и xcode? я думал это где то на уровне файлов приложухи делается, не посоветуете почитать начальное что нибудь?

Comment: @V.Baryshev сложно что-то советовать.. я бы почитал обычную матьчасть, которых в интернете полны полном, какую, выбирать вам. Советовать почитать, как именно пишутся сетевые приложения на android - я не могу.. исходят из опыта программирования и осмотра чужого кода.. многие пишут свои "костыли" для реализации энного.. это касается как обычной платформы ( Windows), так и друих

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял ситуацию, то вам потребуются:

1. Исходный код приложения
2. Ключи для подписи приложения(для андроида это фалй формата .jks, например)

Ваши действия для андроида:

1. Находим человечка, который хоть сколько-нибудь может в андроид, ставим ему пиво или небольшое денежное вознаграждение и он все вам сделает

Если такой вариант по каким-то причинам не вариант, то...

1. Устанавливаем Android Studio, даем ему скачать все, что требуется
2. Пытаемся импортировать проект из папки с исходным кодом вашей программы
3. Долго мучаемся с тем, чтобы все зависимости схватились, докачались, конфликты порешались и т.д. и т.п. Этот процесс каждый раз как в первый раз происходит, по ходу дела у вас будут проблемы возникать и вам придется гуглить/спрашивать тут каждую конкретную проблему
4. Найти в коде место, где хранятся старые ip-шники, заменить их на новые. Скорее всего просто поиском по проекту (ctrl+shift+f) справитесь, даже умение писать код не понадобится
5. В меню Build  кликаем Generate Signed Apk / Bundle. Нужно будет указать путь до вашего jsk файла, пароль от него и название ключа(эти данные вполне могут оказаться только в голове у разработчика...)
6. Заливаем сгенерированный apk/aab файл в Play Market как новую версию вашего приложения

Самый муторный пункт - третий. Без пятого ваше собранное в файл приложение не скушается плеймаркетом как обновление, если не найдете jsk или пароли от него, то придется удалять из маркета старое приложение и выкладывать новое с новым ключом.

На iOS вместо Android Studio ставим x-code, который работает только на macOS. В остальное примерно так же все должно сработать, разве что для подписи другие файлы используются и третий пункт должен быть менее муторные. Думаю коллеги, связанные с яблочками поправят меня, если что.

Отдельные "но" могут наложится если вы используете не "натив", а какие-нибудь кроссплатформенные фреймворки, без подробностей трудно что-то еще сказать

PS Для того, чтоб такой проблемы не возникало, лучше вместо ip зашивать в приложение доменные имена. ip могут сменится даже без переезда сервера, а так в днс поменяли и без всяких обновлений у всех клиентов все заработало. В вашем же подходе после переезда пока пользователь не обновится до последней версии программа у него работать не будет